# How to Get Output from R Scripts

Tags: java, r, deployr

I have a .R Script and I am using `deployR`. My application is in Java and I have a client code interacting with the R code. The R code works fine and running it through `deployR` it generates a `csv` file too. This file is the output data that I need in my application.

I tried using the following :

```
RProjectExecution Execution = project.executeScript("XYZ.R", "root", "user", "", ExecutionOptions);
RData rDataOut =  Execution.about().workspaceObjects.get(0);
```

but the value of `rDataOut`  results to `NULL`. I cannot share the whole code due to company policy.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Output files named in the API as artifacts:

```
List<RProjectFile> files = exec.about().artifacts;
```

Read more about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/deployr-client-library